# Describe generic of generic in XML documentations

Tags: c#, xml-documentation, xml-comments

In my interface I have the following method signature:

```
ServiceResponse<IDictionary<int, string>> Dictionary(DictionaryRequest request);
```

I'm trying to add XML comment for that method like:

```
/// <summary>
///     Returns the dictionary of all codes with translations for the requested language.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">The <see cref="DictionaryRequest"/> containing the incoming parameters.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="ServiceResponse{IDictionary{TKey, TValue}}"/> containing codes and values of translations.</returns>
ServiceResponse<IDictionary<int, string>> Dictionary(DictionaryRequest request);
```

What is the proper way to do that? Should I specify type like

```
<see cref="ServiceResponse{IDictionary{int, string}}"/>
```

or it is enough

```
<see cref="ServiceResponse{T}"/>
```

or

```
<see cref="T:ServiceResponse&lt;IDictionary&lt;int, string&gt;&gt;"/>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Doesn't VS make suggestions when typing?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No, in my case no

Comment: the second option is enough. VS will just deduce what T is.